# Under extrusion issue only in one vertical area but inconsistent

Tags: print-quality

This is a new issue to me. I'm using Repetier and Cura to slice. I never had issues prior to this. What is throwing me off is the issue (Which appears to be under extrusion) only occurs on the front right side of the print (Has happened the last two prints) and it went away completely during one print for a good 20-30 layers. The other 3 sides are perfect. I have hundreds of prints on this printer and it's never occurred before and the fact that it is inconsistent has me baffled. Any input would be appreciated.[image: Perfect on 2 other sides.]

[image: Inconsistent extrusion only on one side and it goes away for a few layers?]

Comment: It looks like the bed is not planar to the extruder.

Comment: Why would it all the sudden print perfect for an inch of vertical surface and then revert back on the right print?  I just printed another one (just the bottom 1" to preserve martial/time) and the one at 50% scale looked fine, the one at 100% scale looked much better this time but you can still see some issues.  Both images are the same side, one is the front half of the cube and the second is the second half.  The second half is perfect as you can see. Maybe this closeup will give someone a bit more to go on? I'm trying to  post more detail but I cannot, is there a way to add more detail/pic?

Comment: What's behind/inside those walls? Are there supports? Differences in geometry at the layers it doesn't happen in? I suspect you have some massive oozing going on just before this wall is printed, leaving nothing in the nozzle for a while. You might also inadvertently have coasting turned on (never turn on coasting).

Comment: Did you get it fixed? I have faced the same issuee, always starting at some corner. I have read it is possible to adjust acceleration settings or jerk control.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably start with ensuring the bed is level (you can use a bubble/spirit level if done manually) and/or move any fans in the room as those could cause inconsistent cooling rates causing it to warp (among other issues).

To make troubleshooting easier on yourself and if you are able, try to only print 10 layers or so. This can be done by modifying the G-code by ending the print at a certain height, though some slicer software have a setting for that (I can't remember at this moment which slicing software allows this to be done easily).